# Latest JQuery mobile causes white page on oracle apex applications within iphone/safari browser

Tags: jquery, oracle, jquery-mobile, oracle-apex

I am currently trying to develop a oracle APEX application that will be used on an iphone using jquery mobile framework.

I have seen a few webpages with examples that have successfully done this using jquery mobile version 1.0a4.1.

This version is quite old and I needed to take advantages of some of the fixes that have occurred since then. I tried upgrading to v1.1 final and everything works fine when rendering the page within a browser on my computer (firefox/chrome). But when I try and render the page in safari or on my iphone I just get a complete blank white page.

Does anyone know how to fix this? The only way I can get it to work again is to downgrade jquery mobile to v1.0a4.1

Thanks.

Here is my template for the page

Header

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="&BROWSER_LANGUAGE." xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:htmldb="http://htmldb.oracle.com" xmlns:apex="http://apex.oracle.com">
   <head>
     <title>#TITLE#</title>
     <link rel="icon" href="#IMAGE_PREFIX#favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#IMAGE_PREFIX#favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">#HEAD#

     <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />-->
     <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>-->

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#mobile_style.css" type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body #ONLOAD#>
     <div data-role="page">#FORM_OPEN#
```

Body

```html
  <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <h1>#TITLE#</h1>
      #NAVIGATION_BAR#
  </div><!-- /header -->
  <div id="messages">#SUCCESS_MESSAGE##NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE##GLOBAL_NOTIFICATION#</div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview">
        #REGION_POSITION_01#
        #REGION_POSITION_02#
        #REGION_POSITION_03#
        #REGION_POSITION_04#
        #REGION_POSITION_05#
        #REGION_POSITION_06#
        #REGION_POSITION_07#
      </ul>
      #BOX_BODY#
    </div><!-- /content -->
```

Footer

```html
   <div data-role="footer">
     <h4>#REGION_POSITION_08#</h4>
   </div><!-- /footer -->

   #FORM_CLOSE#
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: we can't help you without seeing any code!

Comment: I have updated it with the oracle application page template. It is hard for me to post all the code because Oracle Apex uses a templates for all of its pages. I hope this makes sense.